# Creating a node in a graph?

Tags: python, redis, nodes, redisgraph

Trying to create a node via python, what I'm doing wrong :

```
In [1]: import redis
   ...: from redisgraph import Node, Edge, Graph

In [2]: r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379)

In [3]: g = Graph('graph', 'r')

In [4]: test3 = Node(label='test3', properties={ 'abc' : 9, 'age': 33})

In [5]: g.add_node(test3)

In [6]: g.commit()
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b6b3d9b0a206> in <module>()
----> 1 g.commit()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redisgraph/client.pyc in    commit(self)
    134             query = query[:-1]
    135 
--> 136         return self.query(query)
    137 
    138     def flush(self):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redisgraph/client.pyc in  query(self, q)
    153         statistics = None
    154         result_set = None
--> 155         response =   self.redis_con.execute_command("GRAPH.QUERY", self.name, q)
    156 
    157         result_set = response[0]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute_command'
```

---

Found the error :

```
g = Graph('graph', 'r')
```

should be :

```
g = Graph('graph', r)
```

Comment: What is the data type of `query`?  What data type does `self.query` require?  To be safe, can you change your variable name, so that it doesn't collide with the method name?

Comment: i dont do a query yet... the module commit() method does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Found the error :

```
g = Graph('graph', 'r')
```

should be :

```
g = Graph('graph', r)
```